# Differential problem neeed to be solved

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be the function defined by

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}2x-x^2,  x\leqslant 1\\x^2 + kx+p,  x> 1\end{matrix}\right.$

(1). For what value of $k$ and $p$ will $f$ be continuous and differentiable at $x=1?$

(2). For what value of $k$ and $p$ found in (1), on what inteval and intervals is $f$ increasing?

(3). Determine the global maximum and minimum values in the interval $\left [ -2,2 \right ]$

question:To do this question, do I differentiate $f(x)$ first?

Comment: How do you check continuity ?

Comment: Do I use the limits?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: So the limit of top side is 2x-2 and bottom side is 2x+k. what do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

- $f(x)$ is continuous iff
  $$\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2+kx+p)=\lim_{x\to 1}(2x-x^2)$$
- $$f^\prime(x)=\begin{cases}2-2x& x\leq 1\\ 2x+k& x<1\end{cases}$$
  When is $f^\prime(x)$ positive?
- $$f^\prime(x)=\begin{cases}2-2x& x\leq 1\\ 2x+k& x<1\end{cases}$$
  When is $f^\prime(x)=0$? At these points, if the sign of $f^\prime(x)$ changes from $-$ to $+$, you have a relative minimum, and if the sign of $f^\prime(x)$ changes from $+$ to $-$, you have a relative maximum. **Don't forget to check the endpoints!**

Comment: How to find the maxumum and minimum exactly?

Comment: @user136877 As I said, find where the derivative is $0$. At these points, if the sign of $f^\prime(x)$ changes from $-$ to $+$, you have a relative minimum, and if the sign of $f^\prime(x)$ changes from $+$ to $-$, you have a relative maximum. **Don't forget to check the endpoints!**